# Dataflow : Cannot read and write in different locations: source: asia-south1, destination: us-central1"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am getting the below error when running the dataflow. My Datasource is in GCP BQ(asia-south1) and Destination is PostgreSQL DB(AWS -> Mumbai Region).

```
java.io.IOException: Extract job beam_job_0c64359f7e274ff1ba4072732d7d9653_firstcrybqpgnageshpinjarkar07200750105c51e26c-extract failed, status: {
  "errorResult" : {
    "message" : "Cannot read and write in different locations: source: asia-south1, destination: us-central1",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  },
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Cannot read and write in different locations: source: asia-south1, destination: us-central1",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "state" : "DONE"
}.
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.executeExtract(BigQuerySourceBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.extractFiles(BigQuerySourceBase.java:121)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySourceBase.split(BigQuerySourceBase.java:139)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.splitAndValidate(WorkerCustomSources.java:275)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.performSplitTyped(WorkerCustomSources.java:197)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.performSplitWithApiLimit(WorkerCustomSources.java:181)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSources.performSplit(WorkerCustomSources.java:160)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkerCustomSourceOperationExecutor.execute(WorkerCustomSourceOperationExecutor.java:77)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:391)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:360)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:288)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:134)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:101)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My code is as below:

```
      p
      .apply(BigQueryIO.read().from("datalake:Yearly2020.Sales"))
      .apply(JdbcIO.<TableRow>write()
     .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xx.xx:1111/dbname")
        .withUsername("username")
        .withPassword("password"))
      .withStatement("INSERT INTO Table VALUES(ProductRevenue)")
      .withPreparedStatementSetter(new BQPGStatementSetter()));

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

I am running the pipeline as below:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs run sales_data \
--gcs-location gs://datalake-templates/Template   \
--region=asia-east1 \
--network=datalake-vpc \
--subnetwork=regions/asia-east1/subnetworks/asia-east1 \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Bigquery is the source it runs load jobs which stages data in gcs buckets. The data is staged in `temp_location` and if `temp_location` is not specified then it used the region specified in `staging_location`.

In the dataflow job can you specify `temp_location` with a bucket that is created in `asia-south` as that is where your Bigquery dataset is.

Also, if you are using network and subnetwork it is also advisable to turn off public ip so that the connectivity is done via the VPN.

Comment: We tried running with disabling the public ips with no-use-public-ips but it gives the error "Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory".